# How to Open With a Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How would I use a batch file like so: `restart.bat explorer.exe`

What variable would "explorer.exe" be held in?

The batch file, for example, would look like this:

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im %VARIABLE%
start %VARIABLE%
color b
echo COMPLETE
timeout /t 10
exit
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you should use to reference the input parameter given the following: `restart.bat explorer.exe` is `%1`, however to cater for possible spaces e.g. `restart.bat program name.exe`. you may be better asvised to use `"%*"`. Also because `.BAT` is included in `%PATHEXT%`, you don't need to use the `.bat` extension, i.e. `restart explorer.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `explorer.exe` would be in the `%1` batch parameter.

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im %1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this in your batch file :

`%1` represent the parametrer

In your case `%1` would be replaced by `explorer.exe`

```
restart.bat explorer.exe
```

```bat
@echo off
color b
taskkill /f /im %1
start %1
echo COMPLETE
timeout /t 3 /nobreak>nul
exit
```